# Creating a new array by summing/subtracting characters of two strings

Tags: arrays, assembly, sum, difference

Starting from 2 arrays of bytes, S1 and S2, there should be created a third array, based on the following rule: on the even positions should be the sum of the specific characters from S1 and S2, on the odd positions should be difference of the specific characters from S1 and S2

Example:

;S1: 1, 2, 3, 4

;S2: 5, 6, 7, 8

;D: 6, -4, 10, -4

I've tried implementing it the following way, based on 2 "for loops", but after trying several times, I figured out it will probably never work, because they're not simultaneous. I've considered going just with one and based on a comparison, to create the sum or the difference. Thing is, I'm not quite sure on how that comparison should go (cmp si, ?). Any suggestions regarding this would be much appreciated.

```
ASSUME cs:text_,ds:data_

data_ SEGMENT

s1 db '1','2','3','4'
l equ $-s1 
s2 db '5','6','7','8'
d db l dup (?)

data_ ENDS

text_ SEGMENT
start:
mov ax, data_
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
mov si, offset s1
mov bx, offset s2
mov di, offset d  
cld
mov cx, l 
jcxz endi

xor cx,cx   ; cx-register is the counter, set to 0
loop1:
    lodsb    ;current character of s1 is stored in al
    add al, byte ptr es:[bx] ;the character of s2, which is on the same position as the one stored in al, is added to al
    stosb   ;data from al is moved to di
    add cx, 2   ;cx is incremented
    cmp cx,l    ; Compare cx to the limit
jl loop1   ; Loop while less 

mov al, 0   ; al is emptied
mov cx, 1   ; cx-register is the counter, set to 1
loop2:
    lodsb   ;current character of s1 is stored in al
    sub al, byte ptr es:[bx] ;the character of s2, which is on the same position as the one stored in al, is added to al
    stosb  ;data from al is moved to di
    add cx, 2 ;Increment
    cmp cx,l    ; Compare cx to the limit
jle loop2   ; Loop while less or equal

endi:
   mov ax, 4c00h
   int 21h
text_ ENDS
end start
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for any mistakes/inconveniences.

Comment: The double loop approach could also work but you need to reinitialize `si` and `di` (make sure both start at the second item).

Comment: Note: "ASCII code" is a [genericized](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Genericized) term for "character code". If you make assumptions about the character encoding (codepage) in your program, you should add that to the documentation. Go `chcp` in your console to see which character encoding  _your_ console is expecting when _you_ run your program. ASCII itself is quite rare or specialized—it's never been the default on OSes for Intel PC hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jester has pointed out, the double loop could work, this is just merely an example of how I would do it. This example however is destructive, insomuch as the contents of s1 are being modified. If you wanted to use this model, but modify to comply exactly with your example, the modification should be pretty easy to conceptualize.

```
    ASSUME cs:text_,ds:data_

        data_ SEGMENT
    s1 db '1','2','3','4'
    s2 db '5','6','7','8'
        data_ ENDS

        text_ SEGMENT
    start:
            mov     ax, data_
            mov     ds, ax
            mov     es, ax

            mov     si, offset s1
            mov     di, offset s2
            mov     cx, di
            sub     cx, si              ; Now you have the number of entries in CX
            xor     bx, bx
            jcxz    endi

        Next:   
            lodsb
            mov     ah, [di]
            bt      bx, 0               ; Is bit on, then we want to subtract
            jnc     @F - 2
            sub     al, ah
            jmp     @F
            add     al, ah

     @@:    stosb
            xor     bl, 1               ; Toggle add or subtract indicator
            loop    Next

        endi:
            mov     ax, 4c00h
            int     21h

        text_ ENDS
    end start
```

NOTE: I use NASM, so hopefully this example is workable with MASM

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with the code.

1. You cannot add or substract **characters**. A character is not stored as a number but as an ASCII code. You can imagine ASCII codes as a command to the monitor to display a certain character. The processor needs another format to handle it as integer. You have to convert it (and back if you want to have it displayed). The ASCII part of a character is in the high nibble. To get a integer remove it (`AND 0Fh` or `SUB 48`). To get a character add the ASCII part to the integer (`OR 30h` or `ADD 48`). The ladder is the main part of your homework since it is a little bit challenging to handle the negative signs and the number with more than one digit.
2. SI, DI and BX have to be incremented by 2 with your 2 loops solution. `LODSB` and `STOSB` only increment by 1. So you have add an extra incrementation for that registers. You forgot to increment BX.
3. It doesn't matter here, but... `JL` and `JLE` perform **signed** comparisons. It's unlikely that CX becomes negative. So change it to the unsigned camparisons `JB` and `JBE`.

The following code stores the results as integers in `d`:

```
ASSUME cs:text_,ds:data_

data_ SEGMENT

s1 db '1','2','3','4'
l equ $-s1
s2 db '5','6','7','8'
d db l dup (?)

data_ ENDS

text_ SEGMENT
start:
mov ax, data_
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
mov si, offset s1
mov bx, offset s2
mov di, offset d
cld
mov cx, l
jcxz endi

xor cx,cx                       ; cx-register is the counter, set to 0
loop1:
    lodsb                       ; current character of s1 is stored in al
    mov ah, byte ptr es:[bx]    ; the character of s2, which is on the same position as the one stored in al, is added to al
    and ax, 0F0Fh               ; Remove the ASCII parts in AH and AL
    add al, ah
    stosb                       ; data from al is moved to di
    add bx, 2                   ; Increment
    add si, 1                   ; Increment
    add di, 1                   ; Increment
    add cx, 2                   ; cx is incremented
    cmp cx,l                    ; Compare cx to the limit
;jl loop1                       ; Loop while less
jb loop1                        ; Loop while below

mov si, offset s1 + 1           ; Reinitialize SI, DI and BX at odd indices
mov bx, offset s2 + 1
mov di, offset d + 1
mov cx, 1                       ; cx-register is the counter, set to 1
loop2:
    lodsb                       ; current character of s1 is stored in al
    mov ah, byte ptr es:[bx]    ; the character of s2, which is on the same position as the one stored in al, is added to al
    and ax, 0F0Fh               ; Remove the ASCII parts in AH and AL
    sub al, ah
    stosb                       ; data from al is moved to di
    add bx, 2                   ; Increment
    add si, 1                   ; Increment
    add di, 1                   ; Increment
    add cx, 2                   ; Increment
    cmp cx,l                    ; Compare cx to the limit
;jle loop2                      ; Loop while less or equal
jbe loop2                       ; Loop while below or equal

endi:
   mov ax, 4c00h
   int 21h
text_ ENDS
end start
```

A comparison in a one-loop solution is quite easy. Think binary! An odd number has a 1 in the rightmost bit, an even number a 0. You can `AND` the number with 1 and get a 0 (not set) or 1 (set). `TEST` is a special x86 instruction that performs an `AND` but only sets the flags and doesn't change the register. The zero flage is not set (see `JNZ`) if the result is not null -> odd number.

```
ASSUME cs:text_,ds:data_

data_ SEGMENT

s1 db '1','2','3','4'
l equ $-s1
s2 db '5','6','7','8'
d db l dup (?)

data_ ENDS

text_ SEGMENT
start:
mov ax, data_
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax
mov si, offset s1
mov bx, offset s2
mov di, offset d
cld
mov cx, l
jcxz endi

xor cx,cx                       ; cx-register is the counter, set to 0
loop1:
    lodsb                       ; current character of s1 is stored in al
    mov ah, byte ptr es:[bx]    ; the character of s2, which is on the same position as the one stored in al, is added to al
    and ax, 0F0Fh               ; Remove the ASCII parts in AH and AL
    test cx, 1                  ; Odd?
    jnz odd                     ; Yes -> jump to the subtraction
    even:
    add al, ah
    jmp l2                      ; Skip the subtraction
    odd:
    sub al, ah
    l2:
    stosb                       ; data from al is moved to di
    add bx, 1                   ; Increment
    add cx, 1                   ; cx is incremented
    cmp cx,l                    ; Compare cx to the limit
jbe loop1                       ; Loop while below

endi:
   mov ax, 4c00h
   int 21h
text_ ENDS
end start
```

Comment: What a coincidence i was about to post exactly the same answer :)

Comment: IMO characters **are** exactly stored as numbers, it's just one has to mind the encoding, i.e. "digit zero" character is not value zero in memory, but actually understanding that everything in computer starts as value composed from bits (0/1) is important. I find your wording a bit unfortunate, and in clash with my perspective.

Answer (score 0):

> I've considered going just with one and based on a comparison, to
>   create the sum or the difference.

**This is how you do it with just one loop (where you do sum or the difference based on value of index):**

Just replace your two loops with the following code:-

```
  mov cl, 2              ; store 2 in cl which is used to check later if the index is even or odd
  loop1:
        lodsb            ; current character of s1 is stored in al
        mov dl, al       ; save al in dl   
        mov ax, si       ; store the value of si in ax
        dec ax           ; since lodsb increments si we have to decrement it to get the current index  
        div cl           ; divide al with cl
        mov al, dl       ; get the stored value from dl to al 
        cmp ah, 0        ; check if remainder is zero (div instruction stores remainder in ah and quotient in al if divisor is 8bit)
        jne oddNum       ; if no then we are at odd position otherwise we are at even position 
        add al, byte ptr es:[bx] 
        jmp continue
        oddNum:
        sub al, byte ptr es:[bx]      ;the character of s2, which is on the same position as the one stored in al, is added to al
        continue:
        stosb                ; data from al is moved to di    
        inc bx               ; increment bx so that it points to next element in s2 
        cmp si,l             ; Compare cx to the limit
    jl loop1                 ; Loop while less
```

In the above code you would do sum or the difference based on the value of si register (which can be either even or odd)